# Using Countifs with dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using some formulas in Excel but not getting the correct result

This formula works fine:

```
=IF($I$44=$I$44,COUNTIFS('Cardiff - Coded to site'!N:N,'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!$M$44,'Cardiff - Coded to site'!H:H,'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!C49),"-")
```

but when I add in another criteria to count only date >= is shows 0 - But the results should have some counts in it. Why it doesn't?

Here is the formula to check the date:

```
=IF($I$44=$I$44,COUNTIFS('Cardiff - Coded to site'!N:N,'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!$M$44,'Cardiff - Coded to site'!H:H,'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!C49,'Cardiff - Coded to site'!E:E,">="&'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!I45:K45),"-")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of `=IF($I$44=$I$44...`?

Comment: `...'Cardiff - Coded to site'!E:E,">="&'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!I45:K45...` why the `'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!I45:K45` as the criterion? That are three cells but should only one. So where is the date really? Also make sure, that both `'Cardiff - Coded to site'!E:E` and `'CARDIFF DASHBOARD'!I45` are really date values and not only text which looks like a date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't need the IF in the end, and you pretty much spotted yourself.

Turned out that the date cell was merged with another cell causing the issue.